# Is it allowed for a muslim to keep secrets? If yes then isn't keeping secret a kind of cheating?

Tags: hadith

Am I allowed to keep secrets in Islam?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Your question title includes more information than the content of your post. Without more input the answer might be subjective which means the question is a bad fit for our site without a focus or more details.

Comment: In what sense is secret-keeping a type of cheating? Sure, some secrets (e.g. not entirely informing the buyer about the product in business) could be cheating, but not all secrets.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the details. A secret should not be kept which harms the rights of another innocent person. Otherwise keeping secrets is not forbidden, rather there are secrets which are commanded, recommended or permissible to keep.

It is proven from the Quran that the [Jacob](https://quran.com/12/5), [Joseph](https://quran.com/12/77), the mother and sister of [Moses](https://legacy.quran.com/28/7-13), the [companions of the cave](https://quran.com/18/19), [Muhammad](https://quran.com/66/3) ﷺ etc. kept secrets. Also it is  recommended for the believers to keep their [charity a secret](https://quran.com/2/271). And it is permitted for an oppressed person to keep [his faith a secret](https://quran.com/16/106).

Similarly in ahadith you may find that the Prophet would keep his [war plans](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/160) secret and he would confide secrets to some of his companions such as [Fatimah](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/129) and [Anas](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/61) who then guarded the secrets entrusted to them, and he emphasized guarding [other people's secrets](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/65) as a trust and [condemned revealing secrets](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1437a) of one's spouse.